# Representation and heuristic of Connect6 game in Prolog

Tags: artificial-intelligence, prolog, heuristics, game-ai

I want to represent game connect6 [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect6) (maybe predicate stone(P, X, Y), where P is player, X,Y are coords would by good). Also I want to use any good heuristic to solve the problem (to make opponent). Can you give me a hint to any article about game AI in Prolog? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. But I do not want to copy-paste any code. I just want to find the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax game trees. To optimize the search, you probably don't want to consider all possible moves. Maybe just moves that are in-line with an existing piece and 6 or less spaces from it.

Then you need an http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_function. Probably something like assigning a score to "how close am I to completing a line" overall the lines in progress.

Building and optimizing a game tree is more of a mechanical process. Creating an evaluation function is the fun part that will give your AI opponent it's unique flavor.

Searching google for "minimax game tree prolog" turned up a nice powerpoint:
http://staff.science.uva.nl/~arnoud/education/ZSB/2009/

Answer (score 2):

If you're implementing Connect6 on a finite board, then a possible representation for this game would be a list of lists of variables, initially unbound. You'd "place a stone" by unifying a variable with one of the atoms `black` or `white`. You can then test whether a position `P` is still empty with `var(P)`. This representation should be a lot faster to manipulate than a list of `stone/3` terms. It works because in Connect6, you can't ever remove a stone.

I assume that by *heuristic* you mean an evaluation function suitable for minimax, negamax or alpha-beta search. Considering the game rules, I'd suggest that for each player, you count the number of rows of length five and score those 5, score those of length four 4, etc. This gives you two scores S<sub>1</sub> and S<sub>2</sub>. Subtracting S<sub>2</sub> from S<sub>1</sub> yields the relative advantage for player 1. Then find some way to normalize these into the range [-1,1] or score a situation where the game is over infinity of minus infinity. (How to represent all that in Prolog is left as an exercise.)